# Asymptotic relation of $\sum_{n > x}\frac{1}{n^2}$

Tags: asymptotics, analytic-number-theory

In Apostol's Analytic number theory I encountered the following asymptotic relation. I do not know how this is obtained. Since, I am a beginner to this subject kindly provide a detailed explanation and point me to some resources where I can study more about this.

> $\displaystyle O\left (\sum_{n > x}\frac{1}{n^2}\right) = O\left (\frac{1}{x} \right)$

Comment: Just use bound by $\int_x^{\infty} \frac 1 {t^{2}} dt $ as you do in the Integral test for convergence of a series of positive terms.

Comment: Hint: approximate the sum by an integral $\sum\limits_{n>x}\frac{1}{n^2} \sim \int_x^\infty \frac{dt}{t^2} = \frac1x$

Comment: Or bound it using $\sum\limits_{n\geqslant x}\frac{1}{n(n+1)}$ evaluated exactly.