# Show that $\sum^\infty_{n=m}\frac{1}{n^2} = O(\frac{1}{m})$

Tags: real-analysis, asymptotics

I have been told it is very simple, but I cannot work it out. I was thinking I use that I know the left hand side converges?

Comment: Compare the sum to the integral $\int_m^\infty dx/x^2$ or $\int_{m-1}^\infty dx/x^2$. It does not matter which since their difference tends to $0$ as $m \to \infty$.

Comment: Please describe what have you tried to solve this problem so we can help you :)

Comment: You can do it by integration

Comment: Already [asked](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3941105) here, and not just once (I suspect).

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3361638/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2591225/42969.

Answer (score 3):

If $m\geq 2$, then
$$
\sum\limits_{n = m}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{n^2 }}}  \le \sum\limits_{n = m}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{n(n - 1)}}}  = \sum\limits_{n = m}^\infty  {\left( {\frac{1}{{n - 1}} - \frac{1}{n}} \right)}  = \frac{1}{{m - 1}} \leq \frac{2}{m}.
$$

Comment: Incidentally, the outer inequality still holds when $m=1$